Build Qtreeview with expandable item in column 1, 2 or 3 instead of column 0
I am trying to achieve a Treeview like this:

It is easy to do with a QtreeWidget, however I am struggling to achieve the same thing with a QtreeView.
Every time I try to insert a row with empty cells in the first columns.
There is no more child to that row.
Every time I insert columns in rank 0, I lose the children.
Here is my base code to fill the model from a nested dictionary structure (in the form of
{wellname_i:{depthtype_i:{logtype_i:[loglist]}}}
def fillWellTree(self, parent, dico):
        if isinstance(dico, dict):
            for key, value in dico.items():
                item1 = QStandardItem(str(key))
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    parent.appendRow(item1)
                    self.fillWellTree(item1, value)
                elif isinstance(value, list):
                    parent.appendRow(item1)
                    for val in value:
                        item_i=QStandardItem(val)
                        item1.appendRow(item_i)

for example trying something like the code below as a test will just prevent the item_i to appear in the tree:
def fillWellTree(self, parent, dico):
        if isinstance(dico, dict):
            for key, value in dico.items():
                item1 = QStandardItem(str(key))
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    parent.appendRow(item1)
                    self.fillWellTree(item1, value)
                elif isinstance(value, list):
                    parent.appendRow([QStandardItem(""),item1])
                    for val in value:
                        item_i=QStandardItem(val)
                        item1.appendRow(item_i)

Any hint or help will be much appreciated?
EDIT in case it helps someone:
Finally found the issue in one of the posts : Only the first column item will display the childrens.
so the solution here in the test would be use a list of QStandardItem with empty item in the first columns. The parents must then be the first item of the list (something like: itemlist1[0].appendRow(itemlist2))
if there is a better approach I am open to all comments.

To clarify your edit, that's exactly what is internally done in your example with QTreeWidget (which in reality is a QTreeView with its own model). Specifically, QTreeView only allows one column to have children, which must also be the first column of the model. The items you're seeing in the other columns in the image are not children of the items above in their column, but they all are children of the item in the first, and you simply left the first column empty for that row. It's possible to show items with children in another column, by moving the first column of the header, but then »

the expand icon will still be shown in that column only: that only changes the display order of the model columns, the logical index of the column that shows children will still be the first in the model, therefore the visual first column will actually show the contents of that column for the children of the real first column.

Answer is in the EDIT of the Question:
Only the first column item will display the children. So the solution here in the test would be use a list of QStandardItem with empty item in the first columns. The parents must then be the first item of the list (something like: itemlist1[0].appendRow(itemlist2))
